# Track file in master repository which is ignored in submodule

Tags: git, git-submodules, gitignore

I have a structure like this:

```
/.gitignore
/submodule/.gitignore
/submodule/file.txt
```

Inside my submodule the `.gitignore` file ignores `file.txt`. That is very much logical for the submodule. But in my root I would like to add `"file.txt"` to the repo. Is that even possible?

```
!submodule/file.txt
```

Adding the line above to `/.gitignore` does not work. So for my main repo I would like to overwrite and add it to git but the submodule prevents me from versioning the file.

Comment: I’m not sure if you can add files that belong to a submodule, but you could always try to add it using `git add --force submodule/file.txt`. That should ignore all gitignore rules (so you don’t actually need to add a exception to your gitignore file).

Comment: When trying this I get a fatal: fatal: Pathspec 'submodule/file.txt' is in submodule 'submodule'

Comment: Then you have your reason: You can’t add paths that already belong to a submodule.

Comment: But in my root I would like to add "file.txt" to the repo. Is that even possible? - what do you mean here? If you want to add this file to any other folder except module's folder you should be OK with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nopes, you can't do that. Any file within the submodule can not be added to the master project. It doesn't matter whether it is tracked or not, it just can't be added since the namespace overlaps.

If you really need to do this, then have this file tracked in some other directory (not a submodule) within the master repository, and create a symlink to it in your submodule.

So your structure becomes something like:

```
/.gitignore
/submodule/.gitignore
/submodule/symlink_to_others_file.txt
/others/file.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually `.gitignore` from submodule doesn't affect root repository and vice versa. You have to treat root repository and submodule repository as 2 different repositories with their own `.gitignore` files. So if you added `file.txt` to `rootrepo/submodule/.gitignore` you will not be able to place `file.txt` under submodule folder unless you force git to do this (`git add --force file.txt`). At the same time you have to be absolutely OK with adding `rootrepo/file.txt`.